# SQL - Select rows with common item names and different prices and showing the lowest discount without duplicates

Tags: mysql, distinct, min

We have a table in which we have the  product ID, the price, and the shop ID.
the key is on the couple (product-id/shop-id) so we can have twice the same product in the same shop.

```
table item_price


Product_ID | Shop_ID | Price
1 | 2 | 25.99
1 | 3 | 40.00
1 | 1 | 10.00
2 | 9 | 32.00
3 | 2 | 78.00
```

and a table Item_reference which contains the Product_name, product_id and the retail_price_eur

```
Item reference

 product_title | product_id | retail_price_eur
    product_1 | 1 | 19.99
    product_2 | 2 | 29.99
    product_3 | 3 | 79.99
```

My goal is to select the product 1, for which the discount is the bigger with the following request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.product_id
     , t2.retail_price_eur
     , t2.product_title
     , t1.price, CEIL ((t1.price-t2.retail_price_eur)/t2.retail_price_eur*100) AS product_discount
   FROM item_price AS t1
   JOIN item_reference AS t2 
     ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
  WHERE t1.product_id = 1 
    AND NOT retail_price_eur = 0
  ORDER 
     BY product_discount DESC
```

so, I have a couple of issue:

Issue 1)

Even tho I put DISTINCT, I have duplicates of the same product_id...
(but if i only ask for "SELECT DISTINCT t1.product_id" without any other field from t1 i do not have duplicates). So I have an issue I do not understand..

Issue 2)

I do not know how to integrate the code allowing to select the smaller Minimum Discount.

I would assume something along the line of

```
"WHERE NOT retail_price_eur = 0  AND MIN(product_discount)"...
```

but this is not the correct answer and i do not know how to put it in.

PS: I use "min()" on product discount, as in some cases, the % of variation might be positive if the shop price is superior to the retail price.

here are the command to create the example:

```
CREATE TABLE evilbrick.item_price ( product_id INT NOT NULL , shop_id INT NOT NULL , price FLOAT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MyISAM;"

CREATE TABLE evilbrick.item_reference ( product_title VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL , product_id INT NOT NULL , retail_price_eur FLOAT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO item_price (product_id, shop_id, price) VALUES (1, 2, 25.99)
INSERT INTO item_price (product_id, shop_id, price) VALUES (1, 3, 40)
INSERT INTO item_price (product_id, shop_id, price) VALUES (1, 1, 10)
INSERT INTO item_reference (product_title, product_id, retail_price_eur) VALUES ('product_1', 1, 19.99)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry thank you, is it better with the command to recreate the exemple?

Comment: First, some observations: In each case, you need to identify your PRIMARY KEY. Further, 'price' is rarely FLOAT; it's why DECIMAL was invented, and people get upset if they're short-changed, even by a few pennies.

Comment: And if your RDBMS is using MyISAM by default, then it's likely to be woefully out-of-date

Comment: I am using the sql on the winamp package ... 
I do have primary keys set up on my environement, but for the sake of the command to recreate this exemple table, i don't think that would affect the experience. :)